# Team Foundation Server - undo file lock for all users or workspaces

Tags: tfs, locking, undo

I need to create a scheduled task to remove a file lock or undo pending changes for a specific file (let's call this file $\MyProject\MyFile.cs). 
I know I can do this via the TFS command line utility using `tf undo`, which requires you to specify the user and the workspace.

However in this case the scheduled task does not know which user or workspace is locking the file, so I can't specify this in the command.

Is there a way of removing a lock on a file for all users and workspaces?

I had the idea of using `tf status` command to retrieve the user and workspace the file is locked to, then passing this into my `tf undo` command, but `tf status` seems to only show me the user and **not** the workspace name.

Apolgies in advance if there is already an answer to this question. I've been looking for hours and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check case: [tf.exe undo pending changes from other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653117/tf-exe-undo-pending-changes-from-other-users), the answer in this case gave the solution to get all workspace:

[tf status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9s5ae285.aspx) supports a **/format** parameter. The *brief* output (which is the default) doesn't include the workspace. the *detailed* one does.

> tf status "$/MyProject" /s:MyServer /u:* /recursive /format:detailed

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!